# Passing a List<string[]> model from a form back to action method

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have form which is made up of a List model. When the form is submitted back to action method, the list is null. How can I set this up?

```
public ActionResult PendingRenewals()
{
    //get list elements
    var customers = get customer that match our criteria;

    //Build list
    List<string[]> renewals = new List<string[]>();
    foreach(var item in customers)
    {
        renewals.Add(new string[] {item.name, item.id, item.PO });
    }
    return View(renewals);
}
```

View

```
   @model List<string[]>
   @using (Html.BeginForm()
   {
       <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
       <table>
           @foreach (var item in Model)
           {
               <tr>
                   <td>item[0]</td>
                   <td>item[1]</td>
                   <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => item[2])</td>
                   </td>
               </tr>
           }
    </table>
}
```

Back to Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PendingRenewals(List<string[]> renewal, string EntityId)
{
    //renewals is always null
    return PendingRenewals();
}
```

**Solution**

Using FortyTwo's idea, I used a string[][] as the model, so the view looks like this (model[i][0]) and model[i][1] are the fields that I need passed back to the controller):

```
            @model string[][]
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Length; i++ )
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@Model[i][2]</td>
                <td>@Model[i][3]</td>
                <td>@Model[i][4]</td>
                <td>@Model[i][5]</td>
                <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i][0]) @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i][1])</td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an old fashioned for loop.  This way, the indexer is used to respect the naming conventions needed by mvc's model binder.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
       {
           <tr>
               <td>Model[i].item[0]</td>
               <td>Model[i].item[1]</td>
               <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].item[2])</td>
               </td>
           </tr>
       }
```

Comment: Using a string[][] as a model, rather then List<string[]> worked for me. Of course that means the view is `@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Length; i++ )
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Model[i][0]</td> ect.. </td>}`

Answer (score 0):

FortyTwo is right that you need to use the indexes to get the right form data for the model binder but I dont think even if you do this that the model binder will be able to make sense of the data you are posting back from the form.

Either way, instead of using a list of string arrays, a better approach that would work is to create a 'customer' type, set your model to be a list of customers, and create an editor for the properties on the customer type.